# Differentiation under the integral sign, question about sign.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to calculate $F(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(sx)}{x(x^2+1)}\,{\rm d}x $ by finding $F'(s)$ through differentiating under the integral sign and then taking its integral. I show that the prerequisites for doing this are fulfilled. I end up with $F'(s)=\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}$.
Taking the primitive, and using $F(0)=0$ i get $F(s)=\frac{\pi \ln|s+1|}{2}$.

The textbook answers $F(s)=\frac{\pi \ln(s+1)}{2}$ for $s\geq 0$ and $F(s)=-\frac{\pi \ln(1-s)}{2}$ for $s\leq 0$.
The problem is im not sure where the information on how to handle the sign of $s$ is lost in the process. Checking the integralform of $F(s)$ i realize that for $s\geq 0$ $F(s) \geq 0$, and $F(s)\leq 0$ for $s\leq 0$ and that $F(-s)=-F(s)$, so the textbook solution does make sense to me, but i would like to know where i lose the correct solution and how to handle this.
Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{dF}{ds}=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{s^2}{1+s^2x^2}\right)dx$. While calculating the second integral, the limit to $\infty$ changes sign with $s$.

Comment: When evaluating the last integral above we can make the subsitution $u = |s| x$ (instead of $u=sx$) to get $F'(s) =  \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{|s| - 1}{(s - 1)(s+1)}$ which is valid for all $s$ (and $F'(s) = \frac{\pi}{2(1-s)}$ for $s<0$).

Comment: Ah! Thank you both, i was indeed sloppy while evaluating the second integral and ignoring the effect of the sign of s on the limit to inf. of arctan(sx). Is there anyway to close the question without getting a regular answer, since i consider the question answered?

Comment: @Winther I'd say that could fit as an answer. Also, the comment by vnd would do. In addition, a _general_ tip to Skentuey is to really use the fact that $F$ is odd. That kind of argument will very often save some tears...

Comment: mickep, i do consider them as proper answers, im not sure how to accept them without having the checkmark available.

Comment: You cannot. If they do not want to write an answer, you can write one yourself and accept it (but consider to give them some time). It is good if questions get selected answers, since otherwise they hang around in the "unanswered question" list. Another option is to just delete the question, but I think that with the right answer, this question could be useful for someone else in the future...

Comment: Gotcha. Ill just chill then, and hopefully one of them writes an answer :)

Comment: @Skentuey I'm far to lazy to write up an answer, but it is perfectly fine to answer your own question (you can also accept it if there are no better answers). That way the question gets answered, and you can build som points to be able to do other stuff on this site (comment / downvote etc.). Just a suggestion.